# Why do I get an error while the error seems handled?

Tags: reactjs, metamask

I have this piece of code:

```
const connectMetamask = async () => {
    try {
        if(!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask");
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
        setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }
}
```

When this code is called, Metamask shows up. When I reject the connection, Metamask returns an error 4001 (as intented) but I can't catch it:

[image]

But also the 'catch (error)' is triggered. Why do I get an error while it seems also been handled? I found it has to do something with Promise, but I can't figure out how to handle this error correct.

Comment: what is the error code printed

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: you said: "But also the 'catch (error)' is triggered" so what is the result of `console.log(error.code)`

Comment: 4001. Both the error in my screenshot as the catched error have the same content. Both code=4001 and message='User rejected the request.'